# Veahavta lereiecha kamocha before davening

Tags: tefilla, love

Heard that there’s a custom of the arizal that Magen Abraham cites that says to say “I accept upon myself the mitzvah of veahavta lereicha kamocha” before davening. Anyone know where this is and have the exact text, as well as when exactly do you say this before tefillah? Before you put on tefillin? Some other point?

Comment: https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C_(%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Magen Avraham (46:1)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95) cites Arizal that one should accept the mitzvah of loving others before Shacharis.

> קודם בואו לבית הכנסת יאמר ואני ברוב חסדך וכו' ובכניסתו יאמר בבית אלהים נהלך
> ברגש (כתבים) **קודם תפלת שחרית יקבל עליו מ"ע של ואהבת לרעך כמוך**
> [הכוונות]:

From the wording of the Magen Avraham, it sounds like this should be done after entering the synagogue, before praying.

This is the implication of R' Chaim Vital (Shaar Hakavanos) who writes to say this before reciting the Parshas HaAkeidah:

> **קודם שהאדם יסדר תפילתו בבית הכנסת** **מפרשת העקידה ואילך**, צריך שיקבל עליו
> מצות ואהבת  לרעך כמוך, ויכוון לאהוב כל אחד מבני ישראל כנפשו, כי על ידי
> זה תעלה תפילתו כלולה מכל תפילות ישראל ותוכל לעלות למעלה ולעשות פרי.
> ובפרט אהבת החברים העוסקים בתורת ביחד, צריך כל א' וא' לכלול עצמו כאילו
> הוא אבבר אחד מן החברים שלו, ובפרט אם יש להאדם ידיעה והשגה לדעת ולהכיר
> לחבירו בבחינת הנשמה, ואם יש איזה חבר מהם בצרה צריכים כולם לשתף עצמם
> בצערו או מחמת חולי או מחמת בנים ח"ו, ויתפללו עליו. וכן בכל תפילותיו
> וצרכיו ודבריו ישתף את חבירו עמו.

However, elsewhere R' Chaim Vital (Hakdamah l'Chochma Haemes) writes that this should be before entering the synagogue.

> **קודם שיכנס** ישים אל לבו מצוות עשה ואהבת לרעך כמוך **ואח"כ יכנס**

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (12:2) writes to say this before every tefillah.

> גם **יקבל עליו קודם כל תפילה**, מצוַת "ואהבת לרעך כמוך", ויכוין לאהוב את
> כל אחד מישראל כנפשו. כי אם חס ושלום יש פירוד לבבות ישראל למטה, אז גם
> למעלה אין התאחדות; אבל התאחדות בגופיהן שלמטה, גורם התאחדות ודבקות
> נפשותיהן למעלה, ועל ידי זה גם תפילותיהן מתאחדות, ואז בהיות תפילותיהן
> כלולות יחד, היא רצויה לפניו יתברך שמו.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

It's in the [Chabad siddur](https://www.sefaria.org/Weekday_Siddur_Chabad%2C_Shacharit%2C_Morning_Prayer?lang=bi), the very first line of shacharis:

> נכון לומר קודם התפלה: **הֲרֵינִי מְקַבֵּל עָלַי מִצְוַת עֲשֵׂה שֶׁל וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ**

Comment: Where's the citation in the MA?

Comment: It wasn't clear that OP was looking for the citation.

Comment: I think you are correct that there was a certain amount of ambiguity in OP's asking "Anyone know where this is and have the exact text," - this could have referred to the MA *or* the nusah used.